# How to run a side quest

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

Recent commitments means one of our group cannot attend our once monthly DnD game for a few weeks. We are in the middle of a campaign, a close knit group and we are usually always present at every meeting (there's only 4 of us). In the player's absence, we have done a few non-DnD evenings but we're all itching to get back into it, so it's been decided we'll do a little mini quest to scratch the DnD itch whilst one of our group is away. The players do not want to re-roll new chars. They want to play as their existing PCs.

I am unsure how best to proceed.

- I could carry on from where we left off in the story and just somehow explain the absence of the PC for a while. This will take some story manipulating and will definitely feel contrived in some respects. Or...
- I could wind the clock back to an earlier time to do some quest that is assumed to have happened in the past but we just never actually looked at it before. Again, a little contrived but possible.

I would love to hear some of your experiences of handling this problem and any other ideas you may have for side quests that don't derail the main story but also don't require a whole lot of story wrangling.

Comment: We're a Q&A that's better suited for specific problems that can conceivably have a single "best" answer. Questions asking for ideas/brainstorming tend to break our voting system because every answer could be equally good/bad. [You may be better off with a forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go) for that sort of thing.

Comment: Conflicted on the VtC: I'm tempted to mark as "primarily opinion-based," but then I checked the "possible duplicate" link. That's a well-received and well-answered question that's just as opinion-based, and not even as well presented as this one. I agree with @PurpleMonkey that brainstorming questions tend to be problematic, but the possible duplicate we like...?

Comment: Understood re comments about specific problems vs brain-storming. The possible duplicate link gave me lots of ideas. Many thanks.

Comment: This and the dupe aren't opinion-based, they can be answered perfectly fine using Good Subjective, Bad Subjective like most gm-techniques questions.